# Show that 4/9 times series of basel problem can be written as following sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given $s:=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$. Show that $1-\frac{1}{2^2} -\frac{1}{4^2} +\frac{1}{5^2} +\frac{1}{7^2} -\frac{1}{8^2} -\frac{1}{10^2} +...+...-...-...=\frac{4}{9}s$. We are supposed to show it by putting the summands of the basel problem series in a different order. Have you got any tips for me? I'm kinda lost. I tried subtracting $s-\frac{4}{9}\cdot s$ but that didn't really help.

Comment: What is the pattern of the denominators?

Comment: @FShrike multiples of 3 are left out, even ones are negative and uneven ones are positive.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:

$$\frac{1}{m^2}s=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(mk)^2}$$

Then we can eliminate thirds as follows, and call it a different series by name $s'$:

$$s'=s-\frac{1}{9}s=\sum_{k=1,k\neq3n,n\in\Bbb N}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

The evens are:

$$\frac{1}{4}s'=\sum_{k\text{ even, not mult. $3$}}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

To keep the odds, and make the evens negative, I must first subtract all the evens, leaving a sum of only odds, and then subtract all the evens again to obtain positive odds and negative evens:

$$s'-\frac{1}{4}s'-\frac{1}{4}s'=\frac{1}{2}s'=1-\frac{1}{2^2}-\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\cdots$$

But $s'=s-\frac{1}{9}s=\frac{8}{9}s$, so your desired sum is $\frac{1}{2}s'=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{8}{9}s=\frac{4}{9}s$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I feel really bad that i can't solve this myself :(

Comment: @EmmaHowe I have simply witnessed many series and series transformations in my study, and I too miss “simple” things like this. Just the other day I asked another user a very similar question

Comment: I just hope next time I have a problem similar to this I will remember your proof and figure it out similar to this :)

Comment: @Emma Howe You should at least upvote this answer and even accept it as "the" good one.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$, we have : \begin{aligned}\small\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(3k-2\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(3k-1\right)^{2}}\right)}&\small=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(3k-2\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(3k-1\right)^{2}}+\frac{1}{\left(3k\right)^{2}}\right)}-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k^{2}}}\\ &\small=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2k-2}}{\left(3k-2\right)^{2}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2k-1}}{\left(3k-1\right)^{2}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2k}}{\left(3k\right)^{2}}\right)}-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k^{2}}}\\ &\small=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{3k-3}}{\left(3k-2\right)^{2}}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{3k-2}}{\left(3k-1\right)^{2}}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{3k-1}}{\left(3k\right)^{2}}}\right)-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k^{2}}}\\\small\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(3k-2\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(3k-1\right)^{2}}\right)}&\small=\sum_{k=1}^{3n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k^{2}}}-\frac{1}{9}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k-1}}{k^{2}}}\end{aligned}

Thus, taking $ n\to+\infty$, we get : \begin{aligned} \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(3n-2\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(3n-1\right)^{2}}\right)}&=\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^{2}}}\\ &=\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\eta\left(2\right)\\&=\left(1-\frac{1}{9}\right)\left(1-2^{1-2}\right)\zeta\left(2\right)\\ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{\left(3n-2\right)^{2}}-\frac{1}{\left(3n-1\right)^{2}}\right)}&=\frac{4}{9}\zeta\left(2\right)\end{aligned}